# LinkedIn API can't add scope and token doesn't have refresh data

Tags: php, linkedin-api

The first issue is that we only have access to the `w_member_social` scope when creating an app.

[image: LinkedIn Scopes]

If we try to add `rw_organization_admin`, `w_organization_social` scopes, then the auth breaks.
If we test with only the `w_member_social` scope, we do get a code back but then when we fetch a token with the code, the access token has no `refresh_token` parameters.

```
{
  "access_token": "BBBB2kXITHELmWblJigbHEuoFdfRhOwGA0QNnumBI8XOVSs0HtOHEU-wvaKrkMLfxxaB1O4poRg2svCWWgwhebQhqrETYlLikJJMgRAvH1ostjXd3DP3BtwzCGeTQ7K9vvAqfQK5iG_eyS-q-y8WNt2SnZKZumGaeUw_zKqtgCQavfEVCddKHcHLaLPGVUvjCH_KW0DJIdUMXd90kWqwuw3UKH27ki5raFDPuMyQXLYxkqq4mYU-IUuZRwq1pcrYp1Vv-ltbA_svUxGt_xeWeSxKkmgivY_DlT3jQylL44q36ybGBSbaFn-UU7zzio4EmOzdmm2tlGwG7dDeivdPDsGbj5ig",
  "expires_in": 86400
}
```

How do we add the `rw_organization_admin`, `w_organization_social` permissions?? How do we get a refresh token? We are trying to list company pages that a user admins, and then post on behalf on this company.

Edit: not sure what's going on, our scopes suddenly changed after adding "Marketing Developer Platform" product that is still under review but still no sign of `rw_organization_admin`, `w_organization_social`

[image: scope 2]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will answer my own question. Here are the steps when you register an app in LinkedIn.

1. When you register your app, you only have access to the `w_member_social` scope
2. Then you can start developing but you will get a token with **no refresh parameters**
3. You need to apply to the `Marketing Developer Platform`
4. While the application is in review, you get 2 additional scopes `r_emailaddress`, `r_liteprofile`
5. When your request is approved, you will get the rest of the scopes and your token will have refresh information

[image: all scopes]

Comment: Will do the process thx !

Comment: @Eric: how do you apply to the Marketing Developer Platform? I don't see an option in any of the dev app tabs but I do see in https://developer.linkedin.com/product-catalog/marketing that it lists the products "Community Management" and "Advertisements" which corresponds to some of the products I can request access for. I apparently can't request for the "Community Management" as it requires the app to be the only product, but I can request "Advertisements", is this what you did?

Comment: https://business.linkedin.com/marketing-solutions/marketing-partners

Answer (score -1):

`https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/authorization`  use this api and also read these guides

[Authenication Code Flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/authentication/authorization-code-flow?tabs=HTTPS)

[Simple Guide](https://esther-liao.medium.com/how-to-get-a-linkedin-access-token-a53f9b62f0ce)